Why are Youtube DATA API V3 quotas used so much?
I started using Youtube DATA API V3 to schedule my youtube videos.
After 3 test uploads I reached the quota limit in my first cloud console project...
I created another project, 2 uploads and the "queries per day" are almost reached!
I do guarantee that no way I did 8300 queries!
I just did 2 upload requests...


Can anyone explain to me why this value here is so high?
How can I increase the quota. If I click edit quotas I see empty screen (see below)


Thanks

If you think this is an error then stackoverflow is not where you'll find support.

I don't know if it is an error or I am missing some calculation, therefore I posted here

For your information YouTube Data API v3 Videos: insert endpoint uses 1,600 quota units.

@BenjaminLoison I clicked the link but don't see any quota

Quota impact: A call to this method has a quota cost of 1600 units. otherwise there is this link https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost

This sounds like a bug in the client application, but it's hard to know for sure with the information you've provided.
Check the number of requests sent by your app by clicking "APIs & Services" from the left menu of the Google Developer Console.
If the number of requests is higher than expected, I suggest attaching the debugger to your application and setting a breakpoint at the point where a video upload is initiated. If you have trouble with the debugger, you can also print some output to the console each time before calling videos.insert().
If you are certain you are not making that many requests, and the Developer Console is reporting otherwise, it's also possible that your API key was stolen. If you think this is the case, you can revoke the credential from the Credentials menu and create a new one. Make sure your computer is running virus scans with the latest updates, and that your API key is stored securely (i.e. not in the application source code on github).
If you think the requests are legit, you can request a quota increase with the link on the Quota docs page:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota
